# I having trouble with null

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a algorithm problem without using STL.......
but an error occured,,,, in function DFS, debugger says that "w" is 0xcccccc........
how can i fix this problem?????

```
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX 1000
using namespace std;
bool visited[MAX];
typedef struct Queue
{
    int rear;
    int front;
    int queue[MAX];
    Queue()
    {
        rear = -1;
        front = -1;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        if (rear == front)
            return -1;
        front = (front + 1) % MAX;
        return queue[front];
    }
    void push(int data)
    {
        rear = (rear + 1) % MAX;
        if (rear == front)
            return;
        queue[rear] = data;
    }
}Queue;
typedef struct NODE
{
    int data;
    struct NODE* link;
    NODE()
    {
        data = -1;
        link = NULL;
    }
}NODE;
typedef struct Graph
{
    NODE*g[MAX] ;


    void insert(int u, int v)
    {
        if (g[u] != NULL)
        {
            NODE*tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            tmp->data = v;
            tmp->link = g[u];
            g[u] = tmp;
        }
        if (g[v] != NULL)
        {
            NODE*tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            tmp->data = u;
            tmp->link = g[v];
            g[v] = tmp;
        }
        if (g[u] == NULL)
        {
            NODE*tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            tmp->data = v;
            tmp->link = NULL;
            g[u] = tmp;
        }
        if (g[v] == NULL)
        {
            NODE*tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            tmp->data = u;
            tmp->link = NULL;
            g[v] = tmp;
        }

    }
}Graph;
void DFS(NODE*g[], int start)
{
    visited[start] = true;
    cout << start << '\n';
    for (NODE*w = g[start]; w; w = w->link)
    {
        if (!visited[w->data])
        {
            visited[w->data] = true;
            DFS(g, w->data);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(false);
    int n, m, v;
    cin >> n >> m >> v;
    Graph graph;
    Queue q;

    while (m-- > 0)
    {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        graph.insert(u, v);
    }

    DFS(graph.g, 1);


}
```

I was trying to solve a algorithm problem without using STL.......
but an error occured,,,, in function DFS, debugger says that "w" is 0xcccccc........
how can i fix this problem?????

Answer (score 2):

You fix problems like this by stepping through your code with a debugger, or sometimes by adding some form of logging. You should be checking that what you thought should be the case when you were writing the code is *actually* the case during the execution of the code.

In this example, if you think `w` should *not* be 0xcccccc then you want to investigate where `w` comes from and why it's not being set to the correct value. You continue following the chain of logic backwards until you find the first point where the program is not doing what you thought it would be doing, and that's your bug.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two issues here:

- You never set any values to `g` so it’s filled with garbage
- you create the new structs with `malloc` while having a construct or defined. It will never be called. Use `new` since this is c++

It’s also very non-c++ to do these `typedef struct` things. Just use `struct X`. And you probably want to use a class rather than struct. This feels like C code copied into C++.

The suggestion of using a debugger is sound. Run your code line by line. Also turn your compiler’s warnings to maximum.

Also I would suggest using a better code style with more spaces (like `NODE *variable` and `...} name`, empty lines between functions etc for readability, especially when showing code to others.

Comment: as `new` could cause memory leak in case of missing `delete`, let smart pointers do that job for you